# A big form need several steps to finish, how to implement it in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, state

In my android application, there is a big form that split into several pages. User can move to previous or next page, and the content has inputted should not be lost.

I'm trying to use several `Activity`s for each page, but I found it hard to keep the inputted text.

Is it right to use `Activity` here? Or shall I use `Fragment` or something else?

Comment: go with Fragments, it will be easier

Comment: ViewPager is also good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You can easily use a custom layout for each page and switch between them using ViewAnimator/ViewSwitcher. That is if you have really simple forms that don't require benefits of fragments.

Using Activity for each page is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use separate `Activity`s or `Fragment`s for this. They are both relatively isolated and can lose their data when they're no longer being viewed.

I would probably create a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) for this, which allows you to swipe between `View`s. There is some sample code available there to show how it's used.

Comment: `ViewPager` may be another good option, I will try it next time, thank you